High Speed and Accuracy in Network Intrusion Detection System
I am designing NIDS. I use AI IDS model to detect attacks. My goal is to improve accuracy and detection speed. The speed is more important! I have two ways.
First, I am going get all packet from network traffic and extract features from each check each packet. And then, I will give this feature values to model directly as input. Then the model will detects attacks. In this method, I will check all packet so the detection speed is too slow.
Also, I have an another way that other person suggests. Second method, "All packet checking is too slow. Also the network traffic contains normal packets more than malicious packets. So all packet checking is not good. So, we have to collect packets from network traffic about each 5 minutes. And then we have to choose some packets from this collections and make a group. The importance, this group should include all attack packets in that group as possible. This is the most important! We can use some ways to choose packets such as statistical method, filter and so on. Finally We will use only chosen packets with a model for detection. With this way, we can achieve high speed and accuracy."
The second way seems to good but I am unusual that I can get high speed when compares to fist method. If it is actually good way, how to choose packets from collections? Are there any other better ways?

Removed the off-topic request for resources.

how to choose packets from collections? - That is for you to decide, it's the key part of your design! If there were a general answer to that question there'd be a load of excellent IDS products on the market. Are there any other better ways? - I'm afraid, opinion-oriented questions are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].
